# Spring Form, commandName and autocomplete="off"

Tags: forms, spring, autocomplete

I want to have the autocomplete="off" attribute on a form. I need it on the form because Firefox ignores it on the individual input elements.

The spring form tag does not support autocomplete and barfs if I try to add it.

If I don't use the spring form I am unable to set the commandName attribute.

Can anyone think of a way to get both autocomplete and commandName working together?

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 3 choices:

- extend the original form tag by your own implementation
- use the bind tag instead of the form tag, then you can write the html form tag like you wast: see http://jroller.com/habuma/entry/spring_form_tags
- add the attribute by java script. for example the dojo framework willl help you

Comment: Tried using bind. It gets values in, but doesn't put the values at form submission into the object.

Comment: @Peter Wilkinson: i recommend extending thw tag too, the other ways are only workarronds, bit i mentond it for compleatness

Answer (score 3):

The spring `form:input` and `form:password` tags **do** support autocomplete. And they work just fine.
Here is the [Spring form tld reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input).

Comment: The Spring 4 form-tld is now here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input